# Can I override the color of a control when Visual Styles are enabled?

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I have an application in C++ Builder 2010 that has Visual Styles/Runtime Themes enabled to use the runtime look for buttons and tabs.  However, I have a set of checkboxes (TCheckBox) for which I would like to override the runtime style, if possible.

My checkboxes are used to toggle some graphical overlays for various colors.  When I have runtime themes disabled, I can set the background of the checkbox to show which color it will enable, like so:
[image: checkboxes with a custom background color]

Is there a way I can achieve this same effect when runtime themes are enabled?

Thanks to stukelly, I can selectively disable visual styles for individual controls, but I seem unable to modify the color or other styling of that control after I call SetWindowTheme as below:

```
SetWindowTheme(CheckBox1->Handle, L" ", "");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put each checkbox on it's own panel and set it to the color you want.

Comment: It's a bit messy with so many panels, but it seems to work, so I'll mark this as the answer for now.

Comment: When themes are enabled a lot of controls get backgrounds drawn by the parent control. The few that don't have a ParentBackground property to control this behaviour like TPanel and Tscrollbox. The ParentColor and by extension Color properties only apply when themes are disabled. While messy using panels works not only with themes but with various skinning libraries like DevExpress' ExpressSkins for VCL.

Answer (score 3):

You could try disabling the theme for each checkbox using the [SetWindowTheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759827%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function.

```
  SetWindowTheme(CheckBox1->Handle, NULL, "");
```

I'm not sure if the second parameter needs to be `NULL` or `L" "` as the documentation mentions.

```
  SetWindowTheme(CheckBox1->Handle, L" ", "");
```

I used the following references to answer this question.
http://www.delphigroups.info/3/7/54654.html
[borland.public.delphi.ide.general](http://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.delphi.ide.general/browse_thread/thread/e3ab3cf0d869848b)

Comment: The second one got me partway there - visual styles are definitely disabled for the controls I pass in.  Only problem is now I can't seem to customize the style TCheckBox after my call to SetWindowTheme, it just retains the default style.  Looks like the guy in the second link had the same problem, but didn't get a direct answer.